# transforming polygons

Tags: ios, graphics, transform

I have made a UIView in which I have collected some points into a closed polygon using CGmutablePathRef.  I am drawing them with a CGContext.  I now want to 'flip' the UIView that these polygons lie in.  I do not have a transform to flip the vertices with though.  Where do I get one?  How do I go about this?  Where do I find some reading material and a code example of what I am generally describing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the answer for me was the CALayer that underlies every UIView.  That CALayer has a method for getting the affineTransform.  The affineTransform can then be modified with CATransform3DMakeRotation.  Rob Napier turned me on to CALayer concept [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324373/how-to-draw-the-vertices-on-a-cgcontext-cgmutablepathref) .  Ray Wenderlich explained access to the CALayer [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/introduction-to-calayers-tutorial) (including drawing to it), and rotating the CALayer was covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362180/rotating-a-calayer-90-degrees).